# Listview how to check if 1 or more string exist

Tags: android, listview

Here is the code I am testing but with no success. I am trying to search for the string `demooo`. In this test, the `demooo` can be in very first index or anywhere, so I am trying to loop through the `listview` to find it. I'm not sure why it's not working.

```
addButtonn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //check listview
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                String strName = "demooo";
                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewfind);
                for (int i = 0; i < listView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                    if (strName.equals((String) listView.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString())) {
                        CharSequence text = "fffffffffffffffound";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                        return;
                    }else{
                        CharSequence text = "nooooooooooot found";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                        return;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Add item to listview:

```
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String strUserName = editText.getText().toString();
                strUserName = editText.getText().toString();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strUserName)) {
                    editText.setError("cannot be emty");
                    return;
                }
                listItems.add(editText.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                                    long id) {
                Toast.makeText(threee.this, "Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Error? Logs? Problem? What's not working?

Comment: it just toast's  not founddddd even the item is in the listview , the app is not crashing.

Comment: Do you have access on your ArrayList or Array that was put in the adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that your listItems is an ArrayList

```
addButtonn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //check listview
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            String strName = "demooo";
            if(listItems.indexOf(strName) > -1){
                   //item is existing in the list
            }
            else{
                 // not existing
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: this worked as i want it very nice bro thanks allot sir love u

Comment: just a quick question     if(listItems.indexOf(strName) > -1){    theis part of the code   >-1  what does it mean? does it mean -Minuse 1 index while searching

Comment: listItems.indexOf(strName) returns the index of the string in the arraylist. If it is -1 , it means that object is not existing in that list

Answer (score 0):

Ungh...

I guess your workflow consists of starting with empty list, and adding a new item each time the user presses the "Add" button. Anyway, instead of searching the ListView for the right String, you should rather search the "listItems" object to see if it contains the proper value.

Read here
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_indexof.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewfind);
List<CreateDao> list = new ArrayAdapter<CreateDao>();
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
EditText editText  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
final String strName = editText.getText().toString;
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
Button addButtonn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

addButtonn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               CreateDao createdao = new CreateDao();
               if(strName.equals(""){
                   Toast.makeText(sample.this, "data empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   createDao.setName(strName);
                   list.addAll(createDao);
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChange();
            }
        }
    });
```